# Self-modifying code sees a 0xCC byte but the debugger doesn't show it?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, breakpoints, self-modifying

I'm trying to write self modifying asm code.

At some point, I try the following : (NASM compiler)

```
start_of_code:
; ... snip ...

cmp byte [rax], 0x66
jae above_label
  add byte[rax], 0x20
; ... snip ...

above_label:
inc rax
loop start_of_code
```

gdb shows the following values at start `x/8xb $rax` :

```
0x12 0x12 0x11 0x20 0x18 0xfe 0x83 0x9b
```

The first two iterations are ok, the `0x12` are compared as I expect and no jump take place. With `0x11` however, `cmp` sets the `OF` flag instead of the `CF`  and `jae` is executed

I have 2 guesses at the moment, either gdb doesn't report the right memory location first, 0x9b is in fact the address being compared, or someplace else. This seems unlikely because the add seems to work like I expect.

Or this might be an alignment problem. Adding NOP instructions before the cmp does seem to affect the outcome in some way. I really have no clue why

edit : 
When I try

```
mov bl, byte [rax]
```

`bl` gets `0xcc`

This doesn't make sense to me. gdb doesn't report any value of `0xcc` anywhere near `[rax]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0xcc` is the machine code for `int3` which is the software breakpoint interrupt. `gdb` places this into your code at breakpoints so it gets control back. It doesn't play well with code that reads itself. Use the `hbreak` command instead, to set a hardware breakpoint that doesn't need to modify your code.

Comment: WOW. It would have taken me a long time to figure this out. Thanks a lot!