# What kinds of bytes does GDB insert in memory to debug the executable?

Tags: binary, x86, gdb, gnu

> What kinds of bytes does GDB insert in memory to debug the executable?

I know that GDB must insert (or manipulate) some bytes in memory, since when I debug a program that computes, i.e., the XOR over a region of memory and set the breakpoint within this region, then the program computes the wrong result.

However, if I do `x` (inspect memory), then everything in memory seems unchanged.

My question  is therefore:

Suppose I set a breakpoint, e.g., `b *0x40206e`. What (invisble) changes does GDB make to the executable within memory to support debugging it?

Comment: Related: [memory location addressing in asm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042713/memory-location-addressing-in-asm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that GDB must insert (or manipulate) some bytes in memory
>   t
>   You know that it does, not that it must.

GDB *could* instead use debug registers to insert (small number of) breakpoints without modifying program code, but it's easier to simply insert `0xCC` at every breakpoint address: doing so doesn't have any limitations, works on all processors, and is simply easier.

Thus, to insert a breakpoint on x86, GDB saves the first byte of the original instruction in its own memory (so it can restore the original instruction later), and overwrites that byte with `0xCC` (the `int3` "trap to debugger" instruction).

> However, if I do x (inspect memory), then everything in memory seems unchanged.

That's because GDB knows where it has inserted breakpoints, and *pretends* that the program code is unmodified (in other words, the `examine` command shows you what is supposed to be in memory, not what actually is there).

If it didn't, it would be very confusing to e.g. issue `disassemble` command and see `int3` and "gargbage" remains of the original instructions.

Comment: So, to insert breakpoints 0xcc, GDB shifts the bytes in memory? I don't see why it would ruin disassemble, since int3 would be shown followed by original instructions (not garbage)?

Comment: @Shuzheng No, it doesn't. It overwrites the original instruction opcode with `0xCC` (and saves the original value elsewhere, so it can restore it later).

Comment: Aha thanks - this also answers my diasssemble question! Thanks.